# after user changed his profile picture should be changed on all over like on his old uploaded posts, old given comments

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am developing a social media website like Facebook, Instagram. I have one problem that if a user updates his profile picture it should be updated on all old posts, also on given comments like exact same Facebook Instagram..how can I do. I have also stored user id on all uploaded posts given comments.

Comment: add some code? there are many ways to do that.

Comment: i just want a idea of how to achieve that.should i change url of old post having a profile picture after user changed his profile picture.